# Access Query: Return all records that occur on a certain day, ignoring the time

Tags: ms-access

I have an Invoices table with a Date/Time field.  I want to write a query that returns all invoices for a certain day.

The problem I'm having is that when I filter the query by a particular date (such as 04/30/2011), no records are being returned.  My suspicion is that Access is trying to return records that are an EXACT MATCH of 04/30/2011.

What I want is a query that returns all invoices that occur ON 04/30/2011 regardless of what time they occur.  Basically, I want Access to care about the day but not the time.

Is there any documentation on how to do this?  I sure can't find any.  I'm using Access 2010.  Thanks!

Comment: Why are you storing a time part of other than 0 in an Invoice Date field? An Invoice Date is a date, it should have 0 as the time component. My guess is that you're populating the field with Now() instead of with Date(), a common mistake that is urged on Access users by a lot of the examples in the sample databases and help files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about the datatype, I assume your date is stored in a `datetime` field. This will store the time as well and if no time is specified will default to midnight. I ususally use the `BETWEEN` function to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2011-04-30' AND '2011-05-01'
```

Because both dates will be at midnight, you will get the results from April 30.

Comment: I'd suggest datefield >= '2011-04-30' AND datefield < '2011-05-01', just in case someone creates an invoice at midnight on 1st May.  :)

Comment: Lane - To expand on Will A's comment, `DateCol Between A and B` translates to `Col >= A And Col <= B`. `Col >= A And Col < B` would be better.

Comment: Or to further muddy the waters how about "WHERE datefield BETWEEN #4/30/2011# AND #4/30/2011# + #23:59:59#"? I use this approach when the date value for the criteria is referenced from a text box on a form.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your attempt, it's hard to say what you're doing wrong. I imagine you're trying to check for equality, which basically will mean that it must have happened exactly at midnight.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= #04/30/2011# AND date < #05/01/2011#`

Comment: Worth noting that you can dynamically "roll" this check based on the given day. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= #04/30/2011# AND date < DateAdd("d",1,#2011-04-30#)`. This is basically Thomas' example, with the very important exception that the right, dynamic check is exclusive and not inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about what Access is doing; when you supply a datetime value with no time, it assumes midnight. So "2011-04-30" means "2011-04-30 00:00:00".

There is a Datediff function in Access that's used like this:

```
Datediff("d", "2011-04-30", [FieldName]) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
DateAdd("d", DateDiff("d", 0, MyDate), 0 )
```

Another choice:

```
CDate(Format(MyDate,"yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

Another variant of solutions mentioned by others that allows you to plug in a single date:

```
DateCol >= #2011-04-30# And DateCol <= DateAdd("d",1,#2011-04-30#)
```